# How to give id to auto generated element automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make a dropdownlist that contains something from my database, all going well until I need to give each of the option unique id

```
 <div class="div3" >
    <select id="input2" class="drop" name="a" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled>a</option>
      <?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) :; ?>
        <option class="option"><?php echo $row1[0]; ?></option>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: _"i need to give each of the option unique id"_ - Why?

Comment: Your `option` tag in the loop does not have a `value` attribute. Is that what you intend to do

Comment: Use your primary key from the table as the HTML ID

Comment: This looks like a typo `:;` The semicolon is not needed

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: yea, im clearly lost at this point, these youtube tutorial confusing af

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an id unique value in option tag, and order you code for make an array with html tag, for example if *$row1[0] = uniqueid*  and *$row1[1] = name*

```
<?php while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
  <option id="<?php echo $row1[0]; ?>" class="option"><?php echo $row1[1]; ?></option>
  <?php }?>
```

Best Regards